# add version to @@WebService

Tags: java

I'm using javax.jws.WebService to create my webservice, in addition to targetNamespace I would like to include a "version" attribute to mark the version of my service. What other tag can I use in addition to this one to accomplish this so my wdsl will look like:

```
<schema targetNamespace="http://example.com/2009/02/15/webservice" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema>
```

i.e. it has a version attribute